# CALayer message while playing video (Xcode 12.5.1, Swift 5)

Tags: swift5, avplayerviewcontroller, xcode12.5

I'm using a stack view to hold various buttons to go to other view controllers, and one button plays a video. Whenever I press this, I get the following messages but the app works fine and the video plays properly:

> CATransformLayer changing property `masksToBounds` in transform-only layer, will have no effect and changing property `allowsGroupBlending` in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Any idea? Video plays ok in simulator and on device.  I'm using the view controller as player like below, Thanks!

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "previewMovie", ofType: "m4v") else{return}
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
vc.player = player
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Can I ignore the message as it doesn't look like a warning or an error and considering the video plays and the app works fine? I have to resubmit the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ignore it. Nothing's wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks matt, that's great to hear! I'm not able to upvote as I'm lacking 'reputation' so pls consider this an upvote. Cheers.

Comment: oh didn't know that, thanks again! Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this message? Other more useful diagnostics get lost in the noise.

Comment: @tomwhipple what other diagnostics are we talking about? You can't filter against particular stuff but you can filter in favor of particular stuff.

Comment: I just mean print statements in my code as well as whatever other unexpected messages get printed. I have a project where many videos are shown in rapid succession, so these messages drown out everything else. If it were feasible to fix the app so these aren't printed, I'd probably do it.

Comment: @tomwhipple What I do is use Logger instead of `print`. This attaches a subsytem name to the output, and you can filter for that in the console, so that all you see is _your_ messages (if that's the goal). The problem with that approach is, of course, that then you _won't_ see messages from the runtime that you might have _wanted_ to see (unless you switch off the filter). — If your real point is that it's darned annoying of Apple to clutter up the console output with their crap, you're right and please file a bug on it.